# Mingw compiles my c code as c++. How do I prevent that?

Tags: gcc, compilation, mingw, codeblocks

When creating a new C-Win32 project in Mingw (gcc) I accidentally added a cpp file as one source file to the other C files.

Now Mingw compiles my c code as c++. I found out by testing that __cplusplus returns true.

I've looked all the project settings in my Codeblock IDE and compared then to other projects that compile as C.

How do I tell Codeblocks/Mingw/GCC to compile it as C source and turn off __cplusplus?

Comment: I'd like to answer myself, I got a tip on Codeblocka forum:
Some C source file names were *uppercase* or contained uppercase letters. GCC appears to think that it then must be a c++ file(!) Changing the names back to lowercase solved the problem.
Now that is a subtle gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

First change the file's extension from `.cpp` to `.c`. To do this:

- Close `file.cpp` in the Code::Blocks editor, if it is open.
- Right click on `file.cpp` in the **projectname** -> **Sources**
  tree-view.
- From the menu select **Rename file...** and name it `file.c`

That should be a sufficient hint to Code::Blocks that you want the
file compiled with the C compiler and not the C++ compiler, *but it isn't*.
When you add `file.cpp` to a project, C::B registers it for compiling
with the C++ compiler and it sticks to that even if you rename the file
to `file.c`.

To make it change its mind you must also do this:

- After renaming the file to `file.c`, once again right-click on it in the project tree-view
  and this time choose **Properties...**
- In the **Properties** dialog, click the **Advanced** tab.
- Change the value of **Compiler variable** from `CPP` to `CC`, then OK out.

Now the file will be compiled with the C compiler.

Comment: I tried that. For some reason __cplusplus is allways defined  199901L allthough my code is C and I've checked the "CC".

Comment: @user1231247 Sorry, I've no further ideas then. This works for me.